# Loading 128 files in parallel in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I have been working on a project and the new requirement is to load 128 files into the physical memory in parallel. All these 128 files reside in the same directory/folder. Is there an algorithm or solution that I can use to solve this problem? I need to code in C++.

Comment: Since what @BenVoigt is true, I'll ask a question to you - are you __sure__ opening the files is the problem? Maybe it's your algorithm for __interpreting__ the files wrong and you should work on that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I completely agree with Ben Voigt's answer, if you really fancy still doing this (if nothing else, to prove to your management that it's not worth doing), then the solution is:

1. Create a list of the 128 files you want to load.
2. For each item in the list, create a thread, give the thread the name of the file and a location to store the data [that is big enough for the content of the file, or a dynamic storage such as a `std::vector`].
3. In each thread, open the given file, read the content into the given storage. Close the file, finish the thread.
4. Wait for all threads to finish.

I can pretty much guarantee that unless you have some really exotic hardware, even at 4 files in parallel, unless the files are tiny, this solution is slower than a sequential process.

Comment: Oh can I pretty-please get another populist badge for this?  ;)

Comment: Ben, It wasn't my plan to "steal the answer". I just felt that the actual question wasn't really answered (even if it's not something you'd want to do...)

Comment: no that is perfectly fine. Green checkmark is only 15 points, and you've done a great job of emphasizing to future viewers that the answer the OP wanted is not actually the thing to do.

Answer (score 10):

The fastest way to load 128 files is sequentially.  Parallelism doesn't work, since the disk heads can't exist in multiple places at a time.  And even with random-access storage such as an SSD, or the disk's DRAM cache, they still have to cross the bus sequentially.

After you read them they certainly can exist in memory in parallel.

I suggest a for loop for checking file size, allocating memory, and reading each file.  The loop will iterate 128 times.  As you get each file, you can start data processing in parallel with subsequent reads.

---

Parallel computation speeds things up because you have a multi-core processor. Overlapped network requests speed things up because there's a long round-trip latency.  **Parallel disk I/O speeds things up only if you have multiple disks, with the data appropriately split among them.** Yours isn't. (And if you use a RAID stripe set, the disk controller will issue parallel reads with no extra work by your application)

If your managers insist "it simply must be read in parallel, there's a requirement", start talking about an array of 128 disks, with a fancy overlay system to make files on 128 disks appear as if they are in the same directory.

The requirement should get more reasonable after that.

Comment: However if the files are too long then loading 128 files will become time consuming. Is there any parallel loop concept in C++ that i can utilize. However I will be generating the ram addresses for these files, start address in memory for each of these 128 files based on their size.

Comment: @user2495173: You can look into OpenMP

Comment: @user2495173: Yes there is, and **it will make reading them even slower**.  You don't want parallel I/O requests to local storage.  Really.  Parallel computation speeds things up because you have a multi-core processor.  Parallel I/O speeds things up only if you have multiple disks, with the data appropriately split among them.  Yours isn't.  (And if you use a RAID stripe set, the disk controller will issue parallel reads with no extra work by your application)

Comment: We do have cases that given a machine with nearly a thousand cores and a storage area network, when input data need some preprocessing before stored in memory, it can be faster to read parallely. However in our case the data needs to be stored in a key-value structure like map(cpp) / hash(perl) / dict(py). I guess it might not be possible though.

Comment: @simonmysun: Note that my comment said "Parallel I/O speeds things up only if you have multiple disks, with the data appropriately split among them."  Your storage network definitely falls into the multiple disks case.